# Chances of Repeating Number

Tags: probability

I am using 6 digit serial numbers, all ending in "0". This means I have 99,999 serial numbers to use before having to start over. 5% of these serial numbers are used for "special parts." The numbers used for that 5% the first time around cannot be used again for any of the 5% of special parts the next time around, but can be used for the other 95%. The question is, what are the chances of a 5% s/n for the special parts that are generated the first time around being generated again for the 5% of special parts the second time around, third time, etc? Please show the formula used to get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A particular number has a $0.05$ chance to be special the first time and $0.05$ chance to be special the second.  The chance it is special both times is then $0.05^2$, so you expect almost $250$ numbers to be reused for special parts on the second pass.

For three passes, a number will be reused three times $0.05^3$ of the time, giving about $12$ numbers and exactly twice $3 \cdot 0.95 \cdot 0.05^2$, where the $3$ is the number of ways to choose the time that is not special, the $0.95$ the chance that time isn't special, and the two $0.05$'s are the chance it is special.  You expect about $712$ of these.  You are in trouble with your plan.